Conjugacy of $x$ and $p$ for simulation of Schrodinger's equation
In Nielsen-Chuang, page 207, there is this box:

I have some strong doubts about the last passage. The logic they follow is that since $H_0$ is diagonal in momentum basis but not in position basis, and $|\tilde{\psi}\rangle$ is in position basis, then we cannot directly apply something of the form $U_1=e^{-ipt}$ to $|\tilde{\psi}\rangle$ since its discretization would be a mess, but we must somehow bring $U$ into position basis.
Here's where I have my doubts: naturally, $U_2=e^{-ixt}$ is diagonal in position basis, but who tells us that $U_{FFT}U_2 U_{FFT}^{-1}$ is too? Exactly because $U_1=U_{FFT}U_2 U_{FFT}^{-1}$, then the right term isn't diagonal in position basis. But the textbook is written as if it were and it solved our problem. As I see it, the problem is not solved.
(Another way to see it is that $U_{FFT}^{-1}$ brings us into momentum basis. At this point, $U_2$ is not diagonal in this basis because it depends on $x$, the same way that $U_1$ isnt in the previous basis because it depends on $p$.)
Is this a mistake of the book? What is the solution to apply $H_0$ in a diagonal way then?
EDIT: Maybe the correct way is to apply $FFT*U_1*FFT^{-1}$, so keeping $U_1$ not $U_2$. If you think about basis change and the representation of operator $U_1$ w.r.t. the different bases, it makes sense to apply $M_{1,p}=\sum_{i=0}^{2^n-1} e^{i p_i t} |p_{i,comp}\rangle\langle p_{i,comp} |$ to $FFT^{-1}|\psi\rangle=|\phi\rangle = \sum_{i=0}^{2^n-1} a_i |p_{i,comp}\rangle$, then applying $FFT$ to go back to x-basis. $M_{1,p}$ is the diag. matrix representation of operator $U_1$ in p-basis. This is overall equivalent to applying $M_{1,x}$ (non-diagonal repr. of $U_1$ in x-basis) to $|\phi\rangle$. Note that $|p_{i,comp}\rangle$ is the computational basis equivalent of $p_i$ ($|p_{0,comp}\rangle = |0...0\rangle$ corresponds to $p_0=p_{min}$. I have written to Michael Nielsen to tell him about this error.

Cross-posted by OP to qc.se

No it's not a mistake. As you said $U_1$ is not diagonal in the $x$ basis but the point of writing $U_1=U_{FFT} U_2 U_{FFT}^\dagger$ is that you know how to implement each gate on the right hand side so you can implement $U_1$ by first applying $U_{FFT}^\dagger$ (as described in Chapter 5), then applying $U_2$ (as described in problem 4.1) and then applying $U_{FFT}$.
The thing is that since we decided that the computational basis $|k\rangle$ represents the eigenstate $|k\Delta x\rangle$ of the $x$ operator, implementing the phase shift $e^{-ix^2/2m}$ is easy for us, while implementing  $e^{i p^2/2m}$ directly is hard.

The problem is that after applying the inverse FFT we are not in position basis anymore but in momentum basis. So the computational basis states are not $|k\rangle$ anymore, but $|p\rangle$ (discretized momentum). So the phase shift with x is no longer applicable in a diagonal way, therefore we still don’t know how to implement that gate.

It doesn't matter what state you are in (the state $|\tilde{\psi}\rangle$ is not an necessarily an eigen state of $x$ anyways). $|p\rangle$ can still be written as a linear super position of $|x\rangle$ basis states, so if you know how to apply $U_2$ on $|x\rangle$, linearity of QM lets you apply it to $|p\rangle$.

Yes, but still it's not diagonal.
Assume that we are in the $|x\rangle$ basis and let's just consider the basis state $|0...0\rangle$ for simplicity. This corresponds to the actual $x={x_{min}}$. So applying $U_2$ to it is straightforward, we just have to do $e^{-i x_{min}t}|0...0\rangle$.
Instead, take $FFT^{-1}|0...0\rangle$. We obtain a complete superposition in p basis. Let's now take the $|0...0\rangle$ term of this sum. This is associated to a momentum ($p_{min}$), so we can't apply $e^{-i x_{min}t}$ to it. $x_{min}$ isn't associated to the new $|0...0\rangle$ anymore.

I've found a possible solution in the edit.
